# In Mulesoft, how to create query parameters with dynamic Key value pair for HTTP Get calls

Tags: specifications, mulesoft, raml

Our requirement is to pass dynamic query parameters in Mule 4, API Specification.

**Example:**

```
http://host:port/fetch-process-api/api/v1/fapi/v1/fetchData?PROGRAM=SharkWeek&S1=E2&Author=David Dobrik&scientist=Riley Elliott
http://host:port/fetch-process-api/api/v1/fapi/v1/fetchData?Shows=BestShowList&Year=2021
```

### Currently we are achieving through below URL:

```
http://host:port/fetch-process-api/api/v1/fapi/v1/fetchData?propertyName=bookPrice&propertyValue=20.0&filter={"condition": "PROGRAM: SharkWeek"}&filter={"condition": "Author: David Dobrik"}&filter={"condition": "Scientist: Riley Elliott"}
```

**In transformations:**

```
EmpFieldValue = attributes.queryParams.propertyValue,
EmpFieldName = attributes.queryParams.propertyName,
FilterArray = attributes.queryParams.*filter
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hi @netiv. Please clarify why the above expressions are not useful, or what they are missing, and provide some examples of the expected output you would like to get with the URL given as the input.

Comment: Hi @aled, which expressions are not useful. 
If you're asking about dynamic query parameters(as shown in example) then I'm seeking help to achieve it. 

If you're asking about what's wrong with current status, as it is not user-friendly and some training and documentation required for all new on-boarding applications. And maintenance has become an issue.

Comment: I understand that your Mule application is receiving an HTTP request with query parameters which contain key-values that you want to use later to filter somehow other information. It is not clear to me how do want those filter to be. Can you share a draft example of the expected 'filter' object given the input of the example (the URL shared)?

Comment: sorry for the late response, I was off till yesterday. Here is the sample of query parameters Required Parameters:  Shows=BestShowList&Year=2021
Filter parameters: PROGRAM=SharkWeek&Author=David Dobrik&SCIENTIST=Riley Elliott. 
Dynamic Query parameter details:
Keys of filter attributes are {PROGRAM,Author,SCIENTIST}
Values of filter attributes are {SharkWeek,David Dobrik,Riley Elliott}

If this is not what you're asking, please share an example so I can understand and provide more details.

Comment: That's one of the inputs that you expect. What would be expected output? I can make some assumptions and see if I can suggest something, but the question is not yet clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'll make some assumptions to try to answer. Because the request is not fully detailed I'll use a generic example of how to implement dynamic filtering.

Let's say I send some filter conditions as query parameters:

```
{
    filter : '{"condition": "PROGRAM: program1"}',
    filter : '{"condition": "Scientist: s2"}'
}
```

so the HTTP request is:

```
GET /filter?filter=%7B%22condition%22%3A%20%22PROGRAM%3A%20program1%22%7D&filter=%7B%22condition%22%3A%20%22Scientist%3A%20s2%22%7D HTTP/1.1
```

I want to filter elements from the payload that match any element of the filter list. One issue I see is that the conditions themselves are not in a standard format, like JSON, so I used the string split function to get the key and value. It would be simpler and safer to parse to use instead the HTTP POST method and a full JSON body with the filtering conditions.

Then I use filter() and for each element of the input payload I compare each attribute with each element of the filters list:

```
    <flow name="filterFlow">
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/filter"/>

        <ee:transform doc:name="Set test payload and create filters variable from query parameters">
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
[
    {
        PROGRAM: "program1",
        Scientist: "s1",
        Author: "Author1"
    },
    {
        PROGRAM: "program2",
        Scientist: "s2",
        Author: "Author2"
    },
    {
        PROGRAM: "program3",
        Scientist: "s3",
        Author: "Author3"
    }   
]]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
            <ee:variables >
                <ee:set-variable variableName="filters" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
 attributes.queryParams.*filter 
    map (read($, "application/json") 
        mapObject { 
                    key: ($ splitBy /\:\s/)[0],
                    value: ($ splitBy /\:\s/)[1]
                    }
                )]]></ee:set-variable>
            </ee:variables>
        </ee:transform>

        <logger message="input=#[payload]"/>
        <logger message="vars.filters=#[vars.filters]"/>        
        
        <ee:transform doc:name="filter payload using filters variable">
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
import * from dw::core::Arrays
---
payload filter (value, index) -> (!(vars.filters some (value[$.key] == $.value)))  
]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>

        <!-- do something with the filtered list -->

    </flow>
```

After filtering only the third element remains. The output is:

```
[{PROGRAM=program3, Scientist=s3, Author=Author3}]
```